# Android Annotations and MonkeyTalk?

Tags: android, aspectj, automated-tests, android-annotations, monkeytalk

I just tried to update my project which uses Android Annotations to include the MonkeyTalk agent. However, as soon as I switch the project to an AspectJ project, all my Android Annotations references are not recognized.

Has anybody successfully used MonkeyTalk in an Android Annotations project?

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 SR2.

It looks like this issue has been raised on the Android Annotations FAQ:
https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FAQ#wiki-aspectj

In order to "fix" it, you have to remove / replace some project properties. I'm worried doing this will cause MonkeyTalk to not work, but I haven't tried it yet.

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: Yes, i tried it, after i changed the properties. Android project changed to the regular one and i coudnt able to record anything in the monkey talk. Any Idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing to this problem before. I added a solution in the [FAQ page of AA](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FAQ#wiki-aspectj). Could you test that and keep me updated ?

Comment: I'm running into a similar situation using ButterKnife.  Won't this solution actually just make it so the Aspects don't get processed?  In that case, the MonkeyTalk functionality won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I had implemented the solution but still my android annotations references are not recognized,please let me know if there is any other way to tackle the same.