# Is it possible to integrate Dagger and AspectJ in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aspectj, dagger

I'm working in an Android project where I'm using Dagger for dependency injection. I don't know so much about Gradle, but as far as I understand, the Dagger annotations are processed by its compiler once the project is built. There's no problem in configuring it as the user guide says. Well, now I want to integrate AspectJ too, so I'm looking at [one of the plugins for Android](https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin).

However, it seems this plugin does a build post processing job to read the aspects too, which remains in conflict with what Dagger compiler does. That's my current *build.gradle* file (Built a test project to have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
}
```

And the Aspect used:

```
@Aspect
public class HelloAspect {
    @Around("execution(void com.mycompany.test.MainActivity.test())")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint pj) throws Throwable {
        Log.d("Prueba","Hello, @Aspect");
    }
}
```

And that's the exception being thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Problem processing attributes in C:\Users\user1\workspaces\android\Test\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\tesicnor\com\test\aspects\HelloAspect.class
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:387)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.<init>(BcelObjectType.java:162)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.buildBcelDelegate(BcelWorld.java:410)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:490)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:456)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:453)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:477)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:904)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at com.uphyca.gradle.android.AspectjCompile.compile(AspectjCompile.groovy:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: bad WeaverState.Kind: -115.  File was :<Unknown>::0
at org.aspectj.weaver.WeaverStateInfo.read(WeaverStateInfo.java:170)
at org.aspectj.weaver.AjAttribute.read(AjAttribute.java:105)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.readAjAttributes(Utility.java:101)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureAspectJAttributesUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:383)
```

It seems AspectJ can't weave `HelloAspect`'s attributes. In fact, it looks like the file itself can't be found (`File was :<Unknown>::0`). So... Can AspectJ be used with Dagger altogether? I have no problems when using them separately.

My Test project in a [zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/epvsf2qo4sf2bjx/Test.zip?dl=0)

**Related:**

- [When I apply AspectJ to Android project with Androidannotations not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199972/when-i-apply-aspectj-to-android-project-with-androidannotations-not-work)

Comment: Please, try out [my aspectj gradle plugin](https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android), it consistently supports Dagger and Android Annotations / ButterKnife (which uses APT) as well. So I think it will solve your problems.
Btw, my mind you don't need runtime weaving, it's enough to compile aj-pointcuts after dagger's compiler. This case is ok in my plugin too. :) Will be appreciate for any feedback!

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @Archinamon!

Answer (score 10):

It looks that you want to use runtime weaving but as I know Dalvik doesn't support this, so you should change your gradle script to get AspectJ compile-time weaving, here you can find two solutions:

- http://architects.dzone.com/articles/working-gradle-spring-aspects
- http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

Comment: I've been looking for the fact that Dalvik doesn't support the runtime weaving and seems [you're right](https://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/tag/aspectj/). For the links, the first one reports a gradle build failure to me, while the second one seems to work more or less (I had a look to it some time ago), but it uses the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`, so it creates a library instead of an application, which I can launch and the aspects are working properly, but I get a warning in Android Studio. +1 for you, but I want to keep my project as an Android Application.

Comment: honestly, I didn't dig too deep in those descriptions, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

I have got this working but would still be considered a "hack" at this stage since you can't simply press the "run" button to install a weaved-dagger-injected app. Here is what I found whilst trying to reinstate my *Spring* -like `@Transactional` database transaction creation point-cuts.

Follow the advice from this [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29417239/1348379) and add in the manual AspectJ parts to your application's `build.gradle`. Attempt to run the project, my project compiled and installed fine but then failed with the dredded;

> "Please ensure code generation has been run on this module"

...error that Dagger generates. Suspecting that it was the weaving emptying the `/gen` folder created by dagger prior to changing the `.class` bytecode I commented out the line;

> apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

...and re-ran the application *without making any code changes*. To my surprise the weaved classes that were generated in the first attempt were maintained and then the dagger module instructions appended! This had the effect of keeping the AspectJ generated code and overlaying the Dagger module instructions! Success? Kind of...there is clearly a conflict (probably around the clearing down of the "gen" folder) that I'll look to overcome next. But, and it's an important but, I am running an app with AspectJ AOP code that uses Dagger for DI... progress...