# Using AspectJ .aj file with Android Studio, weaving appears to not be happening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aspectj, build.gradle

I am new to AspectJ, and we are working on migrating a third-party application originally written using Eclipse to use Android Studio 1.1.0 and Gradle instead.  We have taken an external library this app needs and created a library module in the project, and this library has an AspectJ **.aj** file that we need to compile and have work with the main app for a field-level Observable pattern.  Using the plugin found [here](https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin), I have been able to get the **.aj** file to compile into a **.class** file, verified by looking in the `intermediates` folder.

The problem is coming in the 'weaving' step, where this code is supposed to be injected into the bytecode of the necessary classes.  This does not appear to be happening, as the listeners that are supposed to be notified when a field changes, aren't.  Below are my build files.

**Project build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.12'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app module build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':blahblah')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
}
```

**'blahblah' library module build.gradle:**

```
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

def gsonVersion = '2.2.4'
def aspectjVersion = '1.8.5'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gsonVersion}"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    LibraryPlugin plugin = project.plugins.getPlugin(LibraryPlugin)

    variant.javaCompile.doLast {
        String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                         "-1.5",
                         "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-bootclasspath", plugin.project.android.bootClasspath.join(
                File.pathSeparator)]

        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler)

        def log = project.logger
        for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
            switch (message.getKind()) {
                case IMessage.ABORT:
                case IMessage.ERROR:
                case IMessage.FAIL:
                    log.error message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.WARNING:
                case IMessage.INFO:
                    log.info message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.DEBUG:
                    log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can take a look of [my plugin](https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android) :) Hope it helps! Now it solves almost every existing wish about working with aspectj on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I have been able to get everything working as expected.  Here are the final build.gradle files:

**Project build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app module build.gradle:**

```
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.1'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def gsonVersion = '2.2.4'
def aspectJVersion = '1.8.1'

dependencies {
    compile project(':blahblah')
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectJVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gsonVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

// The section below is what performs the AOP "weaving" (injecting the AOP code into
// the appropriate classes).  Please do not remove.

final def log = project.logger
final def variants = project.android.applicationVariants

variants.all { variant ->
    if (!variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        log.debug("Skipping non-debuggable build type '${variant.buildType.name}'.")
        return;
    }
    JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
    javaCompile.doLast {
        String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                         "-1.5",
                         "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-bootclasspath", project.android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)]
        log.debug "ajc args: " + Arrays.toString(args)
        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler);
        for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
            switch (message.getKind()) {
                case IMessage.ABORT:
                case IMessage.ERROR:
                case IMessage.FAIL:
                    log.error message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.WARNING:
                    log.warn message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.INFO:
                    log.info message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.DEBUG:
                    log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**'blahblah' library module build.gradle:**

```
def gsonVersion = '2.2.4'

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0"
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.12'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gsonVersion}"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
}
```

Comment: You have downgraded the AspectJ version from 1.8.5 to 1.8.1. I think you should go back to 1.8.5 as it contains several bugfixes in comparison to 1.8.1. Anyway, if you have found the solution by yourself, please accept your own answer in order to close the question. It would also have been nice if you had mentioned in prose what you actually had to change in order to make it work and not just the result. It is virtually impossible to do a side by side diff of "before" vs. "after" situation here.

Comment: BTW, you you really want to compile with Java 5 source/target? The way you call the AspectJ compiler with parameter `"-1.5"` says that you want to use Java 5 compliance. If you do that on purpose, fine. Otherwise maybe you want to switch to Java 7 or 8.

Comment: Can the aspect J dependencies be confined to the library only so that it can be published and used by others without knowing that Aspect J is being used underneath.